# Issue updating the library I added manually in iOS project

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, cocoapods

I added a 3rd party library in my project which had some dependencies same as my project. It was successful that time. but now the library was updated and I got it again. This time my project is not build. It has errors like:

> swiftc failed with exit code 1

I cleaned it, but that didn't resolve the problem.

1. is the problem caused because of dependencies?
2. what if it was on cocoapods repository, would I have same problems?

Answer (score 0):

This error is a generic failed to compile code error 
and reasons to this are a-lot 
first make sure that library swift version is the same as version you work on in your project
then 
delete Derived Data folder and Build it.

Go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations for get the derived data path